# Angular ng-show - expression inside

Tags: javascript, angularjs, show-hide

I have such problem - I use `ng-show` to show element and it's base on two things and looks like

```
<div ng-show="{{!data.length && loaded}}"></div>
```

Web inspector shows `ng-show="true"` but style is `display: none` anyway..

Is it expected behavior? Or maybe here's another way to show element with ng-show and some data?

Comment: Remove the {{}} and it will work.

Comment: This is NOT a dupclicate in my opinion.  The question was specifically about detecting 2 conditions.  The supposed original question is not the same.